# Celery: check if a task is completed to send an email to

Tags: python-2.7, flask, celery

I'm new to celery and an overall python noob. I must have stumbled upon the right solution during my research but I just don't seem to understand what I need to do for what seems to be a simple case scenario.
I followed the [following guide](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/using-celery-with-flask) to learn about flask+celery.

### What I understand:

There seems there is something obvious I'm missing about how to trigger a task after the first one is finished. I tried using callbacks, using loops, even tried using Celery Flower and Celery beat to realise this has nothing with what I'm doing...

### Goal:

After filling the form, I want to send an email with attachements (result of the task) or a failure email otherwise. Without having to wonder what my user is doing on the app (no HTTP requests)

### My code:

```
class ClassWithTheTask:
    def __init__(self, filename, proxies):
        # do stuff until a variable results is created
        self.results = 'this contains my result'

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = MyForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # ...
        # the task
        my_task = task1.delay(file_path, proxies)
        return redirect(url_for('taskstatus', task_id=my_task.id, filename=filename, email=form.email.data))

    return render_template('index.html',
                           form=form)

@celery.task(bind=True)
def task1(self, filepath, proxies):
    task = ClassWithTheTask(filepath, proxies)
    return results

@celery.task
def send_async_email(msg):
    """Background task to send an email with Flask-Mail."""
    with app.app_context():
        mail.send(msg)

@app.route('/status/<task_id>/<filename>/<email>')
def taskstatus(task_id, filename, email):
    task = task1.AsyncResult(task_id)

    if task.state == 'PENDING':
        # job did not start yet
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'status': 'Pending...'
        }
    elif task.state != 'FAILURE':
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'status': task.info.get('status', '')
        }
        if 'results' in task.info:
            response['results'] = task.info['results']
            response['untranslated'] = task.info['untranslated']

        msg = Message('Task Complete for %s !' % filename,
                      recipients=[email])

        msg.body = 'blabla'
        with app.open_resource(response['results']) as fp:
            msg.attach(response['results'], "text/csv", fp.read())
        with app.open_resource(response['untranslated']) as fp:
            msg.attach(response['untranslated'], "text/csv", fp.read())

        # the big problem here is that it will send the email only if the user refreshes the page and get the 'SUCCESS' status.

        send_async_email.delay(msg)
        flash('task finished. sent an email.')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    else:
        # something went wrong in the background job
        response = {
            'state': task.state,
            'status': str(task.info),  # this is the exception raised
        }
    return jsonify(response)
```

Comment: I'm voting to close your question. Please work on your problem and reduce it to a [mcve] and then it will be fit for SO. Note that contrarily to your code here, an MCVE *does* run and helps people help you rather than have them chase down artifacts caused by how you presented your problem rather than real issues.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Louis. I'll keep that in mind for next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get the goal of your method for status check. Anyway what you are describing can be accomplished this way.

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
        # ...
        # the task
        my_task = (
                    task1.s(file_path, proxies).set(link_error=send_error_email.s(filename, error))
                    | send_async_email.s()
                  ).delay()
        return redirect(url_for('taskstatus', task_id=my_task.id, filename=filename, email=form.email.data))
```

Then your error task will look like this. The normal task can stay the way it is.

```
@celery.task
def send_error_email(task_id, filename, email):
    task = AsyncResult(task_id)
    .....
```

What happens here is that you are using a chain. You are telling Celery to run your `task1`, if that completes successfully then run `send_async_email`, if it fails run `send_error_email`. This should work, but you might need to adapt the parameters, consider it as pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem right at all:

```
def task1(self, filepath, proxies):
    task = ClassWithTheTask(filepath, proxies)
    return results
```

The line `my_task = task1.delay(file_path, proxies)` earlier in your code suggests you want to return `task` but you return `results` which is not defined anywhere. (`ClassWithTheTask` is also undefined). This code would crash, and your task would never execute.

Comment: Yes indeed my bad, I simplified the  code to make it more readable and added the missing part. :) The code do work actually. But it will send an email only if I refresh my taskstatus route in my browser which is not the behaviour I'm expecting.
I feel badly though that I have a structural problem here, but I have no idea where to start...

BTW I created this class in another python file, because its a bit long, and I didn't wanted to clutter the views.py file of my flask app. Again, I don't know if this was a good idea/practice...